# Using Spearman test to calculate inter rater reliablity when tasks are slightly different

Tags: spearman-rho, agreement-statistics

Spearman test has been used in literature to calculate the reliability of two groups marking/judging the value of a set of scripts by correlating the rank order of the scripts. In a study I had two groups doing this. However, one group provided (very short) feedback on the scripts while the other did not. Does this invalidate the use of Spearman test? That is can I still use it to calculate the reliability of judgements?

Comment: The reliability is what is being measured. In many broadly similar studies the main point is to compare a quick method that may be rough with a slow method that is more thorough, so I can't see that any assumption is being invalidated. You might get more ties with quick rankings, which is always a complication.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Can you please share examples of slow/quick methods you're mentioning, so I can google for studies?

Comment: That seems common in medical statistics, but I don't recall example references.